Is it possible to transform a for loop on CPU using r torch package?
Say I have some code originally work on CPU,
BT <- NULL
for(t in c(1, 2, 3)){
        B_rt <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 2)

        BT <- rbind(BT, t(B_rt))  # update BT

}

I want to know if this piece of code can be transformed using r torch package. I tried below:
BT <- list()
for(t in c(1, 2, 3)) {
  B_rt <- torch_tensor(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 2), device = "cuda")
  
  BT[[t]] <- torch_t(B_rt)
  
}

# Concatenate tensors 
BT <- torch_cat(BT, dim = 0)

But I got error saying
"Error in (function (tensors, dim)  : Indexing starts at 1 but found a 0.
Calls: torch_cat ... call_c_function -> do_call -> do.call -> 
Execution halted"
Thank you very much!

The error is unrelated to CUDA, it will be thrown without setting the device argument. Also, your answer shows that this is a simple error or typo, a reason to close the question.

I then tried to change the dim in torch_cat from 0 to 1
BT <- torch_cat(BT, dim = 1)

And it gives me the expected result
torch_tensor
 1  2
 3  4
 1  2
 3  4
 1  2
 3  4
[ CUDAFloatType{6,2} ]

